# SQL Server 2008 SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my DATA TABLE

### Group     RecvDate    StartDate   EndDate     Status

```
d        7/1/2014                            Pending
d        7/2/2014     7/2/2014   7/2/2014    Completed
d        7/3/2014                            Pending
d        7/4/2014     7/4/2014   7/4/2014    Completed
```

---

![enter image description here][1]
Now what i want do, I want count of status pending like below table.

Result Table:-

### Group       Date range    Pending

```
d          7/1/2014        1
d          7/2/2014        1
d          7/3/2014        2
d          7/4/2014        2
```

---

I am new in SSRS. It will be so helpful if any one give me the concept on that.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood requirement correctly, you wanted to group by date and status.

```
Select col1, col2, case when col4='Pending' then 1 else 2 end as c
from t
group by 
col1, col2, case when col4='Pending' then 1 else 2 end as c
```